# Would installing LAMP fix Django/MySQL config issues?

Tags: python, mysql, django, web-deployment, lamp

Excuse me for the very broad question, but I seem to be going around in circles.

I'm looking to build/develop a `web` application, using a **MySQL** database and host it on my RPi.

In trying to do so, I've learn that I need a **webserver** (apache2 seems to be the one these days) and that I needed to create an `application` to interface between them.

Initially, I was using **Python** and Qt to try and build an app to be the interface, but found out that things weren't simple and I used to use **Python**/**MySQL** connectors etc.

After a few weeks, I got things connected and then thought about the building of it. It became apparent that options like Flask & Django would be better suited for the task due to the frameworks.

I found the DjangoGurls tutorial simple to follow when I read through it, so decided to give it a go, and just had to work out to substitute their **PythonAnywhere.com** deployment example, with my own server..........stuck.

I've got things working on my laptop/development environment, but the server side of things isn't behaving. I know it's to do with the **MySQL** `config/settings/permissions/path` but I can't pinpoint it.

There are so many different tutorials and commands to try, I've lost count, and so many seem to be out of date.

Then I found out about LAMP to add to my confusion, which sounds ideal if I had know about that at the start, but it doesn't include Django or Python, and I need (I think) PHP so I can use **PHPMyAdmin** to manage the **MySQL**.

Is it even possible to install LAMP on what I've already got?
 Would it solve the server side **MySQL** issue?

**EDIT**

I've managed to install pymysql, and when I try runserver I get a config parser error on `/etc/MySQL/my.cnf`
from `/test_blog_app/blog` `pip list` output is below (and I have no idea what most of them are):

```
automationhat (0.0.4)
blinker (1.3)
blinkt (0.1.0)
Cap1xxx (0.1.3)
chardet (2.3.0)
click (6.6)
colorama (0.3.7)
cryptography (1.7.1)
drumhat (0.0.5)
enum34 (1.1.6)
envirophat (0.0.6)
ExplorerHAT (0.4.2)
Flask (0.12.1)
fourletterphat (0.0.2)
gpiozero (1.4.0)
idna (2.2)
ipaddress (1.0.17)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
keyring (10.1)
keyrings.alt (1.3)
lxkeymap (0.1)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
mcpi (0.1.1)
microdotphat (0.1.3)
mote (0.0.3)
motephat (0.0.2)
numpy (1.12.1)
oauthlib (2.0.1)
phatbeat (0.0.2)
pianohat (0.0.5)
picamera (1.13)
picraft (1.0)
piglow (1.2.4)
pigpio (1.38)
Pillow (4.0.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pygame (1.9.3)
pygobject (3.22.0)
pyinotify (0.9.6)
PyJWT (1.4.2)
PyMySQL (0.7.11)
pyOpenSSL (16.2.0)
pyserial (3.2.1)
pyxdg (0.25)
rainbowhat (0.0.2)
requests (2.12.4)
requests-oauthlib (0.7.0)
RPi.GPIO (0.6.3)
RTIMULib (7.2.1)
scrollphat (0.0.7)
scrollphathd (1.0.1)
SecretStorage (2.3.1)
sense-emu (1.0)
sense-hat (2.2.0)
setuptools (33.1.1)
simplejson (3.10.0)
six (1.10.0)
skywriter (0.0.7)
sn3218 (1.2.7)
spidev (3.0)
touchphat (0.0.1)
twython (3.4.0)
urllib3 (1.19.1)
Werkzeug (0.11.15)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was, would installing LAMP solve my MySQL/Django configuration issues, and the answer is no. Installing LAMP over the top would have made things more complicated.

1 - Installed PyMySQL rather than MySQLdb (mainly because I was struggling to install anything else. 
2 - Setup MySQL with a my.cnf file (as per various guides) and after a bit of tweaking and fixing typos, that appears operational. 
3 - Checked MySQL, and there is Django data in the relevant db/table

As far as I can see, Django is now using the MySQL database......

I now have to work out how to configure apache2 correctly, so that it can serve Django for me, without using a port number. I've hunted round and tried various tutorials/commands, no success yet, so will post another question.

Biggest advice - **ALWAYS** check the date of tutorials (or answers) on here and always try to use the most recent one. I've lost countless hours following tutorials that were out-of-date

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the LAMP stack for what you want to achieve. You already picked python as your programming language and django as a framework for your application.

Now you need to face the sysadmin part. When reading about MySQL you often read about to phpmyadmin - which is a graphical user interface for your database server based on PHP. If you want to use it, you need PHP, thats right, but you can also maintain your MySQL database using other tools. E.g. the commandline client called `mysql` or the [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), which you install on your desktop.

When you start diggin into the world of databases there are a lot of things to discover. But don't hesitate. The official documentation has a quite nice [getting started](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/) part. You just need to know how to start/stop the server and how to manage users and permissions. Django usually takes care of all the other things. Of course it is useful to get a deeper knowledge of SQL and the database server at all - but initially it is not needed and there are a lot of developers who do not know more than I described above.

You might also use sqlite on your RPi - it is a filebased database that plays nice with django and is very easy to maintain. If you don't expect high load and massive amounts of data it should usually fit your needs quite nice. And there is no need to install and maintain your database server.

Last but not least you need a webserver that serves your django app. While developing django provides a build in server which makes your life easy. But when installing your app on a server (or RPi) you should pick a real server. I prefer nginx + uwsgi for python projects. But you can of course use good old apache2. The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) is good place to start regarding the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've had a good look through docs, done a couple of udemy courses, followed some digitalocean tutorials, basically started from scratch with a new install, and yet still I get : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?

Losing the will to live! Is it not possible to have Django & MySQL on RPi or something? 
The reason I need to use MySQL over SQLite3 is two have more than one 'user' writing to it.

Comment: Looks like you miss the python bindings for mysql. I would recommend using [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) - IMO it is easier to set up. The README on the github page tells you how to install the lib itself and the necessary binaries in your OS.

Comment: I've been trying to install it but with no success. It's the same problem that I had before I started again

Comment: It would be nice if you add detailed information about the error in your initial question. Relevant information: do you use virtualenv? What is the output of `pip list` when inside your environment (without virtualenv, just run it). Which python version do you want to use. Add the full stacktrace of the error. Plus anything else you might be necessary to know. :)

Comment: I'm not using a virtualenv, although would like to at some stage. I'll have to add the pip list to the OP, as it's too long to list in here. Python3 would be preferred. I have installed pymysql, but I'm now getting a config parser error with etc/MySQL/my.cnf

Comment: It is totally fine to add those information to the question! This looks really weird. Django should not try to parse mysql config at all. Is your mysql currently running? What does `sudo service mysql status` say? First ensure that the database is up and running. Use the same settings as in your django to connect there using the cli. `mysql -p -u yourusername yourdatabasename` - it asks you for the password. If this works as expected, move over to start django.

Comment: I believe so, sudo service MySQL status = active and running, lists as MariaDB but I think that's normal from what I've read?
I can't 'login' to MySQL using username/password, and I'm fairly sure I set a password when I ran the secure installation. Sudo MySQL gets me straight in though

Comment: Oh yeah - of course - debian moved over to mariadb - this is not the same! But however they provide the same interface. can you please add your django database settings to your question?

Comment: I seem to have it operational... I've changed the etc/MySQL/my.cnf to include hostname = local host. I then had a different issue of MySQL access, that I fixed, and it seems to be functional and using the MySQL database. I'm going to crack on and see if I can install Django admin, if I can then it should be working?

Comment: yes, it should work then - if your webserver logs don't cry and you can see any page rendered by your django application it already works...